# Make Rust fallback on traits implemented on variants of an Enum

Tags: rust

I'm on a journey to learn Rust, and i'm trying to implement a priority queue as an exercice.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```rust
struct PriorityQueue {
    vec: Vec<(Thing, String)>,
}

impl PriorityQueue {
    fn push(&mut self, element: (Thing, &str)) {
        let mut inserted = false;
        for (index, inserted_element) in self.vec.iter().enumerate() {
            let (priority, _) = inserted_element;
            if element.0 < *priority {
                self.vec.insert(index, (element.0, String::from(element.1)));
                inserted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if inserted == false {
            self.vec.insert(self.vec.len(), (element.0, String::from(element.1)));
        }
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> (Thing, String) {
        self.vec.remove(0)
    }
}
```

The tricky part is in the `Thing` implementation. I used an Enum because, as i understood, it is the right tool to represent an Union of type. My priorty queue can handle three type as priority score, an usize value, a positive infinite value and a negative one:

```rust
enum Thing {
    Usize(usize),
    NegInf,
    PosInf,
}
```

All necessary traits for comparison are defined on `NegInf` and `PosInf`. If i write a test only with usize number, it works like a charm. If i write a test to ensure NegInf is always lower than any number, it works like a charm. However, if i write a test to ensure NegInf is always upper in my priority queue, among all others usize values. It doesn't.

```rust
    #[test]
    fn test_priority_queue_insert_elements_as_intended() {
        let mut priority_queue = PriorityQueue { vec: vec![] };
        assert!((NegInf < 3)); // Works
        assert!((Thing::NegInf < Thing::Usize(3))); // Doesn't
        //priority_queue.push((Thing::NegInf, "negative infinite"));
        priority_queue.push((Thing::Usize(1000), "one thousand"));
        priority_queue.push((Thing::Usize(10), "ten"));
        priority_queue.push((Thing::Usize(3), "three"));
        //priority_queue.push((Thing::PosInf, "positive infinite"));
        priority_queue.push((Thing::Usize(100), "one hundred"));

        //assert_eq!(priority_queue.pop(), (Thing::NegInf, String::from("negative infinite")));
        assert_eq!(priority_queue.pop(), (Thing::Usize(3), String::from("three")));
        assert_eq!(priority_queue.pop(), (Thing::Usize(10), String::from("ten")));
        assert_eq!(priority_queue.pop(), (Thing::Usize(100), String::from("one hundred")));
        assert_eq!(priority_queue.pop(), (Thing::Usize(1000), String::from("one thousand")));
        //assert_eq!(priority_queue.pop(), (Thing::PosInf, String::from("positive infinite")));
    }
}
```

```
> cargo test
...
thread 'priority_queue::tests::test_priority_queue_insert_elements_as_intended' panicked at src/priority_queue.rs:146:9:
assertion failed: (Thing::NegInf < Thing::Usize(3))
```

I would like to Rust to fall back on the traits implemented on each variant. Or, using another builtin tool to represent my union of type, but that doesn't impersonate them like Enum type seems to do.

You can find the full code here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=10b4cf7bfc8a3db17a55ad4a70d14dbd

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Your `struct NegInf` (and its `PartialOrd` implementation) is unrelated to the variant `Thing::NegInf`. They are named the same, but even in your test cases you might have noticed you referred to one as just `NegInf` and the other as `Thing::NegInf`.

So, when you assert `Thing::NegInf < Thing::Usize(3)`, the implementation being used is the derived one (from `#[derive(PartialOrd)]` on `Thing`).

> When `derive`d on enums, variants are ordered by their discriminants. By default, the discriminant is smallest for variants at the top, and largest for variants at the bottom. Here’s an example:
>
> (source: [`PartialOrd` derive macro documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#derivable))

In other words, `Thing::Usize(_)` is the considered the smallest because it is the first declared variant.

You should not need the `NegInf` and `PosInf` structs; you can simply declare `Thing` this way:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd)] // (and other traits you might need)
enum Thing {
    NegInf,
    Usize(usize),
    PosInf,
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like that was happening. Btw, thanks for the explanation on how the order of declaration influence the comparison. But that doesn't solve the fact that i can't find a way to fallback on the traits implemented on each value of the Enum. Thanks again for your answer !

Comment: @virgilol You _can't_ "implement traits on each value of the enum." The enum is a type, but _its variants are not types._ Therefore, you can implement traits on the enum, but you cannot implement traits on the variants.

Comment: @virgilol Maybe what you want is to remove your `struct NegInf` and replace it with `pub use Thing::NegInf;`, although personally I would just remove the `struct NegInf`  altogether and let the user `use Thing::NegInf` himself as required.

Comment: If i understand well, all i have to do is implement all of my traits on the Enum, handling every cases, instead of having struct outside with their traits implemented. That's sound legit. Thanks !